# Regular Expression in JMeter 2.12

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to use the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter. When I try to parse the following string:

8EC4146730CC4A27afMCCam3ZeAl4uWt3qMMi9cE7Q5YtIkS5BDaba6bI1cgv41dm07wWlFjAmCcRLd97tmLyuO0ycKflQzhaoQS68CGaRo1oqsL1ZQyLGJMM

From the html snippet:

```
<a href="siw_portal.url8EC4146730CC4A27afMCCam3ZeAl4uWt3qMMi9cE7Q5YtIkS5BDaba6bI1cgv41dm07wWlFjAmCcRLd97tm-LyuO0ycKflQzhaoQS68CGaRo1oqsL1ZQyLGJMM" id="STU_COURSE" title="Your course">YourCourse</a>
</dt>
```

Using this Regular Expression:

```
<a href='siw_portal.url\?([^"]+)' id="STU_COURSE" title='Your course'>Your Course</a>
</dt>
```

And Template is set to $1$.

The Regular Expression Extractor doesn't find the string.

Any ideas on why this isn't working, or how to debug this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what does `\?` do after `url` in the regex?

Answer (score 1):

Because you made a mistake with the quotes:

```
<a href="siw_portal.url\?([^"]+)".......title="Your course"
//    __^                     __^           __^         __^
```

instead of

```
<a href='siw_portal.url\?([^"]+)'.......title='Your course'
```

Comment: But actually, chances are that the expression is over-specific. Maybe `/siw_portal.url\?([^"]+)/` already is enough.

Comment: @Tomalak: You're certainly right, I've just kept the OP's regex as is.

Comment: Yeah that wasn't meant as a correction, but as a FYI for the OP.

Comment: I tried your solution using double quotes but still get the same response as with single quotes, the response data gives ava.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 70: http://kusrweb1test.kingston.ac.uk/urd/sits.urd/run/siw_portal.url?Not Set=

Comment: Many thanks for you help, i figured out the solution, this is the regexp i used href="siw_portal\.url\?(.+?)" id="STU_COURSE" title="Your course"

Comment: it appears you have asked to match literal `?` after `url` when no `?` is present. i think that should fail. what is the first `\?` doing in the regex?

Comment: maybe cos your answer doesn't work, doesn't answer questions about how to debug, and no response to the comments..

Answer (score 1):

You can test your regex using any online regex tester, which will help you with simple syntax errors, and also provide hints which cn be really useful for a beginner.

I like this one: http://regex101.com/

You have used different quotation marks in your regex to the sample you are matching, which is why you don't find a match. You are matching `"` when the sample uses `'`.

You can make it work in both cases using `["']` or choose the correct `'` or `"`

In your sample, try:

```
<a href=["']siw_portal\.url([^"^']+)["'] id=["']STU_COURSE["'] title=["']Your course["']>Your Course</a>
</dt>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<a href="siw_portal.url(.+?)" id="STU_COURSE" title="Your course">YourCourse<\/a>
<\/dt>
```